# Create relations and swap id to name in view EF ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two models:

```
public class Project
{
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ShortDesc { get; set; }
    public string LongDesc { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    public List<Note> Notes { get; }
}
```

and:

```
public class Note
{
    public int NoteID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
}
```

My goal is to be able to easily relate Note and Project objects in view.

To store ProjectID in Note object I do:

```
// GET: Notes/Create
public ActionResult Create() {
    ViewBag.Projects = db.Projects.ToList();
    return View();
}
```

And later in Create view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ProjectID, new  SelectList(ViewBag.Projects, "ProjectID", "Name"))
```

Which allows me to pick related project by it's name.

How to correctly swap ProjectID with Project.Name on Index page (where all my notes are shown)?

Also I would like to see related Notes column in Project Index (where all my Projects are listed). Is it possible with use of Notes List from ProjectModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `Project` property to your `Note` class.

```
public class Note
{
    public int NoteID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Tags { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project {set;get;}
}
```

And now you can access this project property in your view

```
@model List<Note>
@foreach(var item in Model)
{
  <p>@item.Name</p>
  <p>@item.Project.Name</p>
}
```